# The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception when configuring Github Self-Hosted Runner

Tags: github, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, github-actions

I am studying Github Enterprise instances and when I am trying to add a new self-hosted runner to my GitHub enterprise instance by following the steps presented at the *Settings/Actions/Runners/Create/self-hosted runner* directory of my organization, I am getting the error shown below at the configuration step:

```
$./config.sh --url <my instance url> --token <my token>

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |        ____ _ _   _   _       _          _        _   _                      |
 |       / ___(_) |_| | | |_   _| |__      / \   ___| |_(_) ___  _ __  ___      |
 |      | |  _| | __| |_| | | | | '_ \    / _ \ / __| __| |/ _ \| '_ \/ __|     |
 |      | |_| | | |_|  _  | |_| | |_) |  / ___ \ (__| |_| | (_) | | | \__ \     |
 |       \____|_|\__|_| |_|\__,_|_.__/  /_/   \_\___|\__|_|\___/|_| |_|___/     |
 |                                                                              |
 |                       Self-hosted runner registration                        |
 |                                                                              |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 # Authentication

 The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
```

I have tried some other [solutions](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/547) on the internet such as disabling the Dotnet socket handler with the `export DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER=0` command but it returns `An error occurred while sending the request.` this time.

I am pretty new at this topic, shall I make some configurations in my Github Enterprise Instance about SSL, can someone help.

Comment: What is the inner exception? Is that not shown? Is there a debug flag that could show you more info?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no debug flag or another log. I don't know how can I examine inner exceptions.

Comment: Have you searched their repo for this error? https://github.com/actions/runner/search?q=The+SSL+connection+could+not+be+established%2C+see+inner+exception+is%3Aissue&type=issues

Comment: Yes, I had searched. The most related solution that I have tried is disabling the HTTP socket handler but it hasn't made any changes.

Comment: Have you installed your org certificate on runner machine?

Comment: What does it mean and how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution that Transport Layer Security (TLS), the successor of the now-deprecated Secure Sockets Layer (SSL). In the docs, you can simply disable it by :

> $ export GITHUB_ACTIONS_RUNNER_TLS_NO_VERIFY=1

Also, I disabled TLS from the Github Enterprise management console. That brought some other errors but they were resolved quickly.

Comment: Did not work for me, I'm running on a Windows 2012 and I've tried to Set the variable, but nothing happens

Comment: @Daniel we're also on Windows 2012 and nothing happens too. Did solve the problem:

Comment: where did you run this command?

Comment: This might work, but it's not a good idea. You want certificate verification enabled to be certain that you're actually talking to GitHub and not some random server somewehre.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved on **Windows Server 2012 R2** (at least in my situation).

Bottom line it landed up being the absence of ciphers enabled in Windows Server 2012 R2 refer point 11 below if you don't want to read the journey!

How I identified my issue:

1. [Checking self-hosted runner network connectivity](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-self-hosted-runners?platform=windows#checking-self-hosted-runner-network-connectivity) provides details of running a test for network connectivity.  **NOTE: I could not get this test to PASS all it's test even after fixing this issue, but I could still register the action-runner and get up and running.**
2. The output of running this provides a link to [Troubleshooting: Why can't I configure a runner?](https://github.com/actions/runner/blob/main/docs/checks/network.md#troubleshooting-why-cant-i-configure-a-runner).
3. Within that it indicates you should be able to navigate to https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/_apis/health from a browser.
4. Navigated using IE and received a message re. TLS and potentially ciphers and does NOT return a successful result.
5. Navigated using Chrome and it returned a successful response.
6. So works in Chrome but not IE.
7. Roll up sleeves.
8. Install [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).
9. Expose **tls.handshake.ciphersuite** in Wireshark [How to find what cipher TLS1.2 is using](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/21696/how-to-find-what-cipher-tls12-is-using/) - Thank you grahamb @ Wireshark.
10. On monitoring the differences between request from IE and Chrome via from Wireshark I established that Chrome was send a different cipher suite and that Wireshark shows the cipher that has been chosen for the TLS communication.
11. **ANSWER HERE ->** More searching then led me to this [Update to add new cipher suites to Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-add-new-cipher-suites-to-internet-explorer-and-microsoft-edge-in-windows-548427db-ed06-5521-fe8b-d525ab573022).
12. Reboot.
13. Re-try registering self-hosted action-runner.
14. **Success!**

[@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1723944/daniel) [@Gustavo Mauricio De Barros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12161568/gustavo-mauricio-de-barros) [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6064946/alex) not sure if you managed to resolve the issue but hopefully that helps.