# Github Self-hosted Runner on Windows machine - SSL connection failure

Tags: windows, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I'm trying to set up a self-hosted Github runner on a remote Windows VM, but while following the guide on their webpage, I get to the step "# Create the runner and start the configuration experience" and get the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |        ____ _ _   _   _       _          _        _   _                      |
 |       / ___(_) |_| | | |_   _| |__      / \   ___| |_(_) ___  _ __  ___      |
 |      | |  _| | __| |_| | | | | '_ \    / _ \ / __| __| |/ _ \| '_ \/ __|     |
 |      | |_| | | |_|  _  | |_| | |_) |  / ___ \ (__| |_| | (_) | | | \__ \     |
 |       \____|_|\__|_| |_|\__,_|_.__/  /_/   \_\___|\__|_|\___/|_| |_|___/     |
 |                                                                              |
 |                       Self-hosted runner registration                        |
 |                                                                              |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 # Authentication

 The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
```

I can't see any inner exception, but this is likely related to a certificate error. There are some posts about people mending this on Linux machines by using "$ export GITHUB_ACTIONS_RUNNER_TLS_NO_VERIFY=1", but what would you do on a Windows machine?

Comment: If you use export in Linux, you need configure as environment in Windows. You could use $ENV:GITHUB_ACTIONS_RUNNER_TLS_NO_VERIFY = 1 or you can do it using the control panel: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried both now, but unfortunately it gives me the same error when trying to run "./config.cmd --url https://github.com/... --token XXX" afterwards.

Comment: Any idea on this? Still no luck with any of the proposed solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71589024/the-ssl-connection-could-not-be-established-see-inner-exception-when-configurin

Running on Windows Datacenter 2019